# Solr standard list of synonyms for english language

Tags: solr, lucene

What I want is for results containing 'car' to also show up if I search for 'vehicle' and other such synonyms in the English language.

I know Solr has SynonymFilterFactory, which is empty by default. But I am curious if there is a standard way to normalize all words for the English language. Should I generate synonyms.txt from a thesaurus?

Is doing this standard practice or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Synonyms are highly dependent on domain of search. Java might mean coffee to a non-programmer - bad example, but hope you got the gist of what I am saying. Generating Synonyms from thesaurus might give you some very confusing results. Who are the audience / customers for your search? You can start by using acronyms and their expansions for your particular domain.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at WordNet.  It's a standard English thesaurus package.  It's included in Python's NLTK package, and it shouldn't be a lot of work to write a script that dumps it out in the format required by SynonymFilterFactory.

But to @jay 's point, you're going to get a lot of hits you probably don't want.  Spending some time to customize your thesaurus to your domain will pay dividends!